# Reading multiple lines of text if it starts with a specific token

Tags: c#

```
:58A:/C/81000098099CL
CBNINGLA
:72:/CODTYPTR/012
/CLEARING/0003
/SGI/DBLNNGLA
```

am trying to read the swift message above, line :58A: and line :72:, am having a little issue. My code only reads line `:58A:` like this `C/81000098099CL`, but I want it to read down the line before getting to line `:72:`, in short, the output should be like this for line `:58A:` `C/81000098099CL CBNINGLA`.

Same also for line `:72:`, this is because the messages come formatted in this form. This is my code below

```
if (line.StartsWith(":58A:"))
{
    string[] narr = line.Split('/');
    inflow202.BENEFICIARY_INSTITUTION = narr[2];
}

if (line.StartsWith(":72:"))
{
    inflow202.RECEIVER_INFORMATION = line.Substring(5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all new lines not followed by `:` with spaces (or empty string).

```
string output = Regex.Replace(text, @"\r?\n(?!:)", " ");
string[] lines = output.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.StartsWith(":58A:"))
    {
    }
    else if (line.StartsWith(":72:"))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Am pretty new to c# and programming, please can you throw more light on Regex

Comment: @user3560266 This one is pretty simple. You want to replace newlines with spaces. But if the next line starts with `:` you don't want to replace the newline. So we are looking for `\r\n` (newline) not followed by `:` - `(?!:)`. Also you may have file that uses UNIX newlines - `\n`, thus we have to make `\r` optional by appending `?`. That gives us `\r?`. Combining all together it would be `\r?\n(?!:)` - new line not followed by line starting with `:`. We replace such match with space. So the text you provided (5 lines) will be converted into text with 2 lines. Then we read line by line.

Answer (score 0):

If the message always comes formatted in this form and `:` never occurs in the text except for these line starters, consider splitting the whole text into an array by `:` first. On 0th position there will be nothing, on all odd positions will be the number, on all even positions will be the content until next `:`. This solution will work providing that you are able to read the whole input into a single string first. I.e. having `string message`, you can do something like:

```
var splitted = message.Split(':');
for (i=1;i<= splitted.Length -1; i+=2){
   if (splitted[i] == "58A") {
       //do what you need to do, the text you need is stored in splitted[i+1]
   }
   ...
}
```